# I want to set background color of a cell to red or green based on pass or fail in python

Tags: python

Please help me in condition check for pass or fail to change background color of a cell in html using python.

my code will check for a couple of values and return pass and fail. now i want to make the pass field in html to green and fail field to RED. Basically to generate a report.

Code snippet

```
def generateReport(reportpath, dict1, dict2):
        html = """<html><body><table border="1"><th>FileName</th><th>MD5</th><th>MD5</th><th><font color="red">MD5 Result</font></th><th>Sha1</th><th>Sha1</th><th><font color="red">Sha1 Result</font></th><th>Sha256</th><th>Sha256</th><th><font color="red">Sha256 Result</font></th>"""
        for key in dict1:
            if(str(dict1[key][0]==dict2[key][0])):
                status1='PASS'

            else:
                status1='FAIL'
            if(str(dict1[key][1]==dict2[key][1])):
                status2='PASS'
            else:
                status2='FAIL'
            if(str(dict1[key][2]==dict2[key][2])):
                status3='PASS'
            else:
                status3='FAIL'
html = html + "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (key,dict1[key][0],dict2[key][0],status1,dict1[key][1],dict2[key][1],status2,dict1[key][2],dict2[key][2],status3)
     html = html + "</table></body></html>"
        newhtml = open(reportpath, "w")
        newhtml.write(html)
        newhtml.close()
```

In the above code , i am facing the problem to add background color based on condition to status1,status2,status3.

please help me.

thanks
praveen.

Comment: Hi, your indentation seems confusing. Please indent the code correctly, especially the part after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To make the background of a table cell red you can use `<td bgcolor="red">`.
If you combine it with your *if statement* you should be fine.

Let me know if you have issues :)